# undefined jquery variable in multiple independent divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this script that grabs the value from an input field then inserts it into the attribute (href) of a link. For some reason, the value is listed as undefined.

Here is the jQuery

```
$(".page_link").click(function() {
                 var page_id = $(this).find(".page_id_value").val();
                 $(location).attr('href',"page_detail.php?page="+page_id);

            });
```

Here is the HTML

```
<a class="page_link" onClick="window.location.href='page_detail.php?page=164';">
     <!--<input type="hidden" class="page_id_value" value="145" />-->
</a>

<a class="page_link" onClick="window.location.href='page_detail.php?page=165';">
     <!--<input type="hidden" class="page_id_value" value="146" />-->
</a>

<a class="page_link" onClick="window.location.href='page_detail.php?page=166';">
     <!--<input type="hidden" class="page_id_value" value="147" />-->
</a>
```

EDIT:The best way to accomplish my goal is to use window.location.href instead of using jquery to change the page. I was using the input field the grab the value for the page variable in the header. The better approach is to just use the window.location.href.   Thanks for the help! The above HTML is corrected and the jQuery is the incorrect approach. This webpage is running in jQuery Mobile.

Comment: What does `$(location)` refer to?

Comment: Its the same thing as href=some web page" or header("Location: some web page"); its jQuery version of that

Comment: Try to use `.prop('value')` instead of `.val()`.

Comment: Dunno what you are referring to, the code works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CXuPQ/).

Comment: The code seems good so far. You might need to post the whole html. But do you have any id with location. Otherwise what it is.

Comment: I think the problem might be that your hidden inputs are actually commented out!?

Comment: The above code works and I just commented them out.

Comment: @Die20 Why are you using javascript to change the page?  Why don't you just use the href.. directly in the `<a>`'s href attribute?

Comment: so does that mean you are not using hidden input fields now. If so why have an onclick handler, why not just set the href on the a tag? All seems a bit of a roundablut way to achieve something that is just basic functionality

Comment: The problem is that I am use jQuery mobile which won't really change the page. Instead is just loads the content for the page but none of the css or js files load alongside with the page. So I have to use javascript to change the page and load all the associated files.

Comment: Perhaps next time then add that you are using jquery mobile

Comment: I assumed it wouldn't make a difference. I will make a note in the edit. Thanks again OJay and Daedalus

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current code is that [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is used to get the *attribute* from html elements.. it does not get or change *properties* from javascript objects, which is what `location` is..  a javascript object.  What you want to use it instead, to change that property, is [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

[Fixed example](http://jsfiddle.net/K38xY/1/)

Comment: You can use location too. It will have the same result. try it in the jfiddle. However, the problem seems to be with the page_id value. When I get to the next page the header displays "page_detail.php?page_id=undefined"

Comment: @Die20 I misunderstood your problem, please see my explanation and example.

Comment: It is still giving me the same issue. Would you reccomend I use window.location.href instead in the html?

Comment: @Die20 Please post the rest of your code.. or if you aren't testing on your local machine, a link to your page.  Also please include your jQuery version as well as browser type and version, so that we can reproduce your current error.